# How can I have multiple instances of same dojo form element with same id in a page?

Tags: dojo, dijit.form

I have a page say profile.htm with dojo declarative form with id="myForm". I have another page say dashboard.htm having border layout with 3 content pane. I want to show the profile.htm in all these three contentPanes. But when I try this then it gives registration error because there will be three forms with same Id.

Is there any solution for this so that I can have same page (with same id) in many contentPanes?

Answer (score 2):

You simply can't, it's because of the HTML spec:

> The id global attribute defines a unique identifier (ID) which must be unique in the whole document.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

The same goes for dijit's, if there are many dijit's with the ID `myDijit` what would `registry.byId('myDijit')` return? Dijit has it's own method of assigning unique ID's just as long as you don't assign one.